# how to write the spark sql DF row into two lines to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

DataFrame :

```
         Df row1 : Ravi  Computers   20

         Df row2 : Jon    Electronics 21

         Df row3 : Sam    arts        20
```

How can I write to write into s3 file as

```
           Line1: Index:Ravi
           Line2: Ravi  Computers   20
           Line3: Index:Jon
           Line4: Jon     Electronics 21
           Line5: Index:Sam
           Line6: Sam     arts        20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing the Spark SQL DataFrame into 2 lines to S3, you have to `map` each row of DF in to respective string with a new line `\n`:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Ravi","Computers",20),("Jon","Electronics",21),
("Sam","arts",20))).toDF

df.map(r => s"Index:${r.getString(0)}\n${r.getString(0)} ${r.getString(1)} ${r.getInt(2)}").write.csv("s3n://........")
```

It will write the DF into expected output format:

```
       Line1: Index:Ravi
       Line2: Ravi  Computers   20
       Line3: Index:Jon
       Line4: Jon     Electronics 21
       Line5: Index:Sam
       Line6: Sam     arts        20
```

Comment: I need to write the string as Json , I tried ur solution with write json("s3:"), but I have ended up something like this  -->  {"value":"Index:Ravi\nRavi Computers 20"} {"value":"Index:Jon\nJon Electronics 21"}

Comment: If you want to write the string as JSON, then you cannot write it in 2 lines. It would produce a corrupt JSON file.

Comment: my df.write.json("s3") is creating individual json files, is it possible to write all the rows at once or append into a single file ?

Comment: Yes, you can create a single file using `coalesce`, like this - `df.coalesce(1).write.json("s3")`.

Comment: If we use coalesce and write to a single file,is the map parallelism compromised ?

Comment: If we use coalesce and write to a single file,is the map parallelism compromised ? Will job run in distributive mode ?

Comment: inside the map I am facing difficulty in writing into like this , can u help with this ?    exp output: {"name":"Ravi","dep":"Computers","age":"10"}    .I can`t write double quote inside a string there.

Comment: To write double quote inside a string use `\"` in scala code, like this - `df.map(r => s"""{\"name\":\"${r.getString(0)}\",\"dep\":\"${r.getString(1)}\",\"age\":\"${r.getInt(2)}\"}""")`. Also, using `coalesce` will not affect parallelism. Your job will run in distributive way. It's just that while writing data, all results of processing will be written to a single file instead of many.